# By Groups in SAS vs window functions in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, sas, hiveql, window-functions

I have a table, input_table, that contains the following columns:

```
key - double
code - string
date- string
result -string
```

I have the following SAS code:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE t1 AS
    SELECT key, code, date, result
    from input_table
    ORDER BY key, code, date;
QUIT;


DATA t1;
   SET t1;
   final_result= INPUT(result, 5.)
RUN;


DATA t2;
   SET t1;
   WHERE NOT MISSING(final_result)
   BY key, code, date

   IF LAST.code;
RUN;
```

So from my understanding, this code is adding column 'final_result', which is result converted to a numerical value, or NULL if it contains non-numeric values. Then it selects rows that have the max date for each key, code pair. I tried to replicate this in hiveQL (which I think is pretty much the same as SQL for this case):

```
select key, code, date, result, final_result 
from
(select *, 
 row_number() over (partition by key, code order by date desc) as rnk, 
 cast(result as double) as final_result
 from input_table
) x
where rnk=1 and final_result is not null
```

Is this query equivalent to the SAS code above? (I would test myself but am having environment issues currently)

Comment: Is `final_result` null ever? If so, then one problem may be that you're restricting it to not null in the outside query - so `rnk=1` may be true on a `final_Result is null` row, which would mean you miss that row entirely.

Comment: Also - much better question, thanks for improving it.  I would recommend adding some example data also (input data) and an example of what you think the output data should look like.

Comment: final_result will be null if result contains any non-numeric characters. I believe that the 'WHERE NOT MISSING(final_result)" line in the SAS code states that we are only selecting rows where final_result is not null, which would be equivalent to the sql @Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only major problem I see with this is that you may have an issue where the last row has a null/missing final result.

In SAS, the `where` clauses takes place before the data step processing, so it's effectively equivalent to having it in the `partition` statement (which I'm not sure if that's possible) and/or in an earlier step.  If the last row by date order happens to be null, SAS will skip it and take the last row that is *not* null (because it won't have been in the data stream to begin with).

In your SQL, though, if rank=1 happens to have `final_result is null`, it will be dropped - but the `rank=2` or whatever row will not be kept (so you'd not have *any* rows for that particular key/code combination in your output).

```
select key, code, date, result, final_result 
from
(select s.*, 
 row_number() over (partition by key, code order by date desc) as rnk
 from (
   select *, cast(result as double) as final_Result
   from input_table 
   where final_Result is not null
   ) s
) x
where rnk=1
```

Something along those lines should be equivalent.

The only other potential issue I could see: If you have two rows with exactly equal dates, SAS will pick the "last" one in the input dataset order.  I don't know what Hive will do; in most SQL implementations, though, you should assume you will get one at random, as SQL won't attempt to preserve the row order.

Comment: Thanks, this response was very helpful. However, the last part about SQL not preserving row order, does this mean that there really isn't a way to get the hiveql to match the sas 100%? @Joe

Comment: It's always possible, just may be more work.  Do you in fact have rows where two key,code rows have an identical (exactly) value for `date`?  Also, from what I remember of your older question, these tables were constructed from SQL in the first place; so it's possible the row order isn't important anyway.  (A straight `select` would usually preserve row order, though not even always there; the partition though could do all sorts of things, including binary trees or such, that could cause the row order to go all over the place.)

Comment: But you can always create a row order variable at the beginning, if nothing else, ie a `row_number` or whatever Hive's equivalent is, and then select based on max(that).

Comment: I would note that I don't know Hive specifically - just SQL in general - so it's worth looking about for Hive specific information about that (preserving row order).  Hive seems like it might have some specific options in that regard.